# Scraping: Acceder a elementos de la tabla siguiente toma el primer elemento

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

URL https://www.pkparaiso.com/pokedex.php

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 html_content = driver.page_source
 driver.get(url)
 html_content = driver.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
      for j in range(72):
           arrows = soup.find('table',attrs={"class":"dex"}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
               for arrow in arrows:
                   names.append(arrow.find_all('td')[2].get_text())
                   print(names)


 time.sleep(.9)
 driver.execute_script("dexlistnext();")
```

tengo ese codigo que itera 72 veces haciendo click en las pestañas siguientes de la tabla pero al cargarlas en la lista, solo agrega los primeros 10 elementos, probe de muchas formas, incluso el Xpath toma como valor al primer elemento por mas que me encuentre en otra ubicación
no pude seguir con el ejercicio porque siempre se llena con los mismos 10 valores iniciales de la tabla

Ejemplo de parte del resultado

`['#001 Bulbasaur', '#002 Ivysaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#004 Charmander', '#005 Charmeleon', '#006 Charizard', '#006 Charizard', '#006 Charizard', '#007 Squirtle', '#001 Bulbasaur', '#002 Ivysaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#004 Charmander', '#005 Charmeleon', '#006 Charizard', '#006 Charizard', '#006 Charizard', '#007 Squirtle', '#001 Bulbasaur', '#002 Ivysaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#004 Charmander', '#005 Charmeleon', '#006 Charizard', '#006 Charizard', '#006 Charizard', '#007 Squirtle', '#001 Bulbasaur', '#002 Ivysaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#003 Venusaur', '#004 Charmander', '#005 Charmeleon', '#006 Charizard'...`

Comment: Y tomar el XML desde https://www.pkparaiso.com/ajax/dex?class!=&at$=&df$=&sa$=&sd$=&sp$=&hp$ no será más fácil??